# Is it possible to change an element's id in response to an event with apps-script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm trying to change an element's id in response to an event but I can't seem to get it to work. I have created a simplified example of what I'm trying to do below.

```
function handleEvent(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app = changeId_(app, 0, 1);
  return app;
}

function changeId_(app, idOld, idNew) {
  app.getElementById(idOld + "element").setId(idNew + "element");
  return app;
}
```

I'm just wondering if it is actually possible to do as I can't think of what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a grid and replace elements in the grid. When you replace elements in the grid, you can use a new ID for the new element/"widget". 
In my case, I repopulate the entire grid to make the code simple, but I think can replace a single element.

Take care with widget IDs, if you reuse an old ID for a new widget, then ensure the widget type of the old and new widget are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible. But why would you want to do that ? If you can give the use case, maybe there is an alternative that the community can help you with.

Comment: Sorry had a few busy days.

In my application the user can search for a name (or part of a name). This populates a list with one returned object to a text box (containing the name) and a save and remove button.

In the database I have a name and id field. However currently if the user changes the name I have no way of knowing the id. So to avoid adding an extra field to the database I wanted to change the id of the buttons to match the id of the object in the database.

Hope that makes sense. I have a work around at the moment using a hidden element.

Comment: Can you think of using ClientHandlers in your code that get invoked when something changes in the list

Comment: The problem is that when the user creates a new entry the application can't possibly know the id of the entry before it is created. Once the entry is submitted for creation I then know the id and need to change it then. I don't think it is actually possible to do it with a client handler. I see where you were going with that idea though.

Comment: To change the ID, replace the element. Use a grid and replace the element. See answer. (Ryan, please consider moving the tick)

Comment: Will do, sorry for the delay. I somehow missed this comment. I gave your answer a plus 1 and just didn't mark it as the answer for some reason. Apologies.